# Stock, Ink and Bindery

Tags: print-design, resolution, paper

my apology. I was searching on the following info, appreciate if you can help. I have some info but need to get additional for my project. Thanks everyone. :D

Describe how paper/stock affects the planning of the whole print process from design through bindery as well as the part it plays in the overall budget of the project. 
List different types of stock like “coated versus uncoated”, plastic, etc., and how a designer needs to know the paper before preparing images because resolution is dependant on line screen which is dependant on stock. Bindery needs of paper plays a factor as well. Also, in printing, Ink is also a factor. Comment on the way paper and ink work together to create a successful projects!

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to GD.SE. :) I'm really not sure what you're trying to ask here. Is there any way you could clarify?

Comment: I'm sorry to be blunt, but this reads a lot like you have copy/pasted your homework assignment. We are not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea for comercial halftone print on a sheeted printer:

If it is **coated**, you can send the file to be used in **150 lpi**. This normally is 300 ppi on raster CMYK images and 2400 ppi on 1 bit images (but you could just send a 1200ppi resolution file)

If it is **uncoated** it could be sent to be printed at **133 lpi**, which gives you normally 266ppi on the cmyk file, but again, you could just send the 300ppi file.

If it is an **art print**, you could try **175-200 lpi**, which could be a 350-400ppi file, but you could get away with the standard 300ppi.

**Newspaper** could be as low as **100lpi** but let them decide. Send your images at 200-300ppi.

---

Not only you need to know the resolution, but also affects the color profile you should be using.

---

The color of the paper also afects the final color, you could simulate this using a color layer on your image and using the multiply blend mode.

---

If the paper is exothic, you probably should use a phisical example.

---

The resolution of images not only depends on the paper, but also depends on the print system. Silk print, offset, flexography.

Comment: If you understand the question could you edit it for the rest of us